# ProgressBar Animated Javafx

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

I wonder if it is possible to make a progressbar with the appearance,"progressbar Animated bootstrap". With stripes going sideways.

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#progress

Comment: Do you mean possible as in 'is there an existing implementation I can use' or possible as 'can I get my component to look like this with some additional work'? The answer to the first question is no, but it is possible with some customization.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**ProgressBar with Static Stripes**

Here is a JavaFX ProgressBar which looks like a static striped progress bar from Bootstrap.

[image: striped]

The stripe gradient is set entirely in css, the Java code is just a test harness.

*File: striped-progress.css*

```
.progress-bar > .bar {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(
        from 0px .75em to .75em 0px,
        repeat,
        -fx-accent 0%,
        -fx-accent 49%,
        derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 50%,
        derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 99%
    );
}
```

*File: StripedProgress.java*

```
import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/** Displays progress on a striped progress bar */
public class StripedProgress extends Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

  @Override public void start(final Stage stage) {
    ProgressBar bar = new ProgressBar(0);
    bar.setPrefSize(200, 24);

    Timeline task = new Timeline(
        new KeyFrame(
                Duration.ZERO,       
                new KeyValue(bar.progressProperty(), 0)
        ),
        new KeyFrame(
                Duration.seconds(2), 
                new KeyValue(bar.progressProperty(), 1)
        )
    );

    Button button = new Button("Go!");
    button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            task.playFromStart();
        }
    });

    VBox layout = new VBox(10);
    layout.getChildren().setAll(
        bar,
        button
    );
    layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));
    layout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    layout.getStylesheets().add(
        getClass().getResource(
            "striped-progress.css"
        ).toExternalForm()
    );

    stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
    stage.show();
  }
}
```

**ProgressBar with Animated Stripes**

JavaFX has good [animation facilities](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/animations/jfxpub-animations.htm) which will allow you to animate the gradient within the progress bar if you wish.

One way to do that is to do a node lookup on the bar after the bar has been displayed on the screen and modify the style property of the bar in a [Timeline](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html), similar to the technique applied in: [How to make an animation with CSS in JavaFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676274/how-to-make-the-css-changing-animation-in-javafx-application)

Personally, I find animated stripes on progress bars annoying.

Writing the actual code for this is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 3):

In another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27533729/2072528) I have explained how to do this.
Like jewelsea said, I animated the hole progress-bar with a timeline. But without a lookup or style change on runtime(both is not really recommended).

You must write a bit more css but then it runs smoothly and without much CPU usage.

Here the edited code from jewelsea:

*File: StripedProgress.java*

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.css.PseudoClass;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/**
 * Displays progress on a striped progress bar
 */
public class StripedProgress extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) {
        ProgressBar bar = new ProgressBar(0);
        bar.setPrefSize(200, 24);

        Timeline task = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(
                        Duration.ZERO,
                        new KeyValue(bar.progressProperty(), 0)
                ),
                new KeyFrame(
                        Duration.seconds(2),
                        new KeyValue(bar.progressProperty(), 1)
                )
        );

        // Set the max status
        int maxStatus = 12;
        // Create the Property that holds the current status count
        IntegerProperty statusCountProperty = new SimpleIntegerProperty(1);
        // Create the timeline that loops the statusCount till the maxStatus
        Timeline timelineBar = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(
                        // Set this value for the speed of the animation
                        Duration.millis(300),
                        new KeyValue(statusCountProperty, maxStatus)
                )
        );
        // The animation should be infinite
        timelineBar.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        timelineBar.play();
        // Add a listener to the statusproperty
        statusCountProperty.addListener((ov, statusOld, statusNewNumber) -> {
            int statusNew = statusNewNumber.intValue();
            // Remove old status pseudo from progress-bar
            bar.pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("status" + statusOld.intValue()), false);
            // Add current status pseudo from progress-bar
            bar.pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("status" + statusNew), true);
        });

        Button button = new Button("Go!");
        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                task.playFromStart();
            }
        });

        VBox layout = new VBox(10);
        layout.getChildren().setAll(
                bar,
                button
        );
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        layout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        layout.getStylesheets().add(
                getClass().getResource(
                        "/styles/striped-progress.css"
                ).toExternalForm()
        );

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

And the full CSS:

*File: striped-progress.css*

```
.progress-bar:status1 > .bar {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(
        from 0em 0.75em to 0.75em 0px,
        repeat,
        -fx-accent 0%,
        -fx-accent 49%,
        derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 50%,
        derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 99%
        );
}
.progress-bar:status2 > .bar {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(
        from 0.25em 0.75em to 1em 0px,
        repeat,
        -fx-accent 0%,
        -fx-accent 49%,
        derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 50%,
        derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 99%
        );
}
.progress-bar:status3 > .bar {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(
        from 0.5em 0.75em to 1.25em 0px,
        repeat,
        -fx-accent 0%,
        -fx-accent 49%,
        derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 50%,
        derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 99%
        );
}
.progress-bar:status4 > .bar {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(
        from 0.75em 0.75em to 1.5em 0px,
        repeat,
        -fx-accent 0%,
        -fx-accent 49%,
        derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 50%,
        derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 99%
        );
}
.progress-bar:status5 > .bar {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(
        from 1em 0.75em to 1.75em 0px,
        repeat,
        -fx-accent 0%,
        -fx-accent 49%,
        derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 50%,
        derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 99%
        );
}
.progress-bar:status6 > .bar {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(
        from 1.25em 0.75em to 2em 0px,
        repeat,
        -fx-accent 0%,
        -fx-accent 49%,
        derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 50%,
        derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 99%
        );
}
.progress-bar:status7 > .bar {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(
        from 1.5em 0.75em to 2.25em 0px,
        repeat,
        -fx-accent 0%,
        -fx-accent 49%,
        derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 50%,
        derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 99%
        );
}
.progress-bar:status8 > .bar {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(
        from 1.75em 0.75em to 2.5em 0px,
        repeat,
        -fx-accent 0%,
        -fx-accent 49%,
        derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 50%,
        derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 99%
        );
}
.progress-bar:status9 > .bar {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(
        from 2em 0.75em to 2.75em 0px,
        repeat,
        -fx-accent 0%,
        -fx-accent 49%,
        derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 50%,
        derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 99%
        );
}
.progress-bar:status10 > .bar {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(
        from 2.25em 0.75em to 3em 0px,
        repeat,
        -fx-accent 0%,
        -fx-accent 49%,
        derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 50%,
        derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 99%
        );
}
.progress-bar:status11 > .bar {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(
        from 2.5em 0.75em to 3.25em 0px,
        repeat,
        -fx-accent 0%,
        -fx-accent 49%,
        derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 50%,
        derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 99%
        );
}
.progress-bar:status12 > .bar {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(
        from 2.75em 0.75em to 3.5em 0px,
        repeat,
        -fx-accent 0%,
        -fx-accent 49%,
        derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 50%,
        derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 99%
        );
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10915118)

Comment: i edited my answer so it meets the criticism points from the reviewers. @MWiesner: It provides an answer to this question if you looked at the link :-/ a better one then the "accepted" in my opinion. now i think it does not earn a downvote :-(

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is interested for the animation version of @jewelsea answer, please check the below code.

[image]

```
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/**
 * Displays progress on a striped progress bar
 */
public class StripedProgress extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) {
        ObjectProperty<Node> node = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
        ProgressBar bar = new ProgressBar(0) {
            @Override
            protected void layoutChildren() {
                super.layoutChildren();
                if (node.get() == null) {
                    Node n = lookup(".bar");
                    node.set(n);
                    int stripWidth = 10;
                    IntegerProperty x = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
                    IntegerProperty y = new SimpleIntegerProperty(stripWidth);
                    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(35), e -> {
                        x.set(x.get() + 1);
                        y.set(y.get() + 1);
                        String style = "-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(from " + x.get() + "px " + x.get() + "px to " + y.get() + "px " + y.get() + "px, repeat, -fx-accent 50%, derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 50%);";
                        n.setStyle(style);
                        if (x.get() >= stripWidth * 2) {
                            x.set(0);
                            y.set(stripWidth);
                        }
                    }));
                    timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
                    progressProperty().addListener((obs, old, val) -> {
                        if (old.doubleValue() <= 0) {
                            timeline.playFromStart();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        };
        bar.setPrefSize(200, 24);

        Timeline task = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(
                        Duration.ZERO,
                        new KeyValue(bar.progressProperty(), 0)
                ),
                new KeyFrame(
                        Duration.seconds(10),
                        new KeyValue(bar.progressProperty(), 1)
                )
        );

        Button button = new Button("Go!");
        button.setOnAction(actionEvent -> task.playFromStart());

        VBox layout = new VBox(10);
        layout.getChildren().setAll(bar, button);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        layout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        
        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```