# JavaFX ProgressBar: how to add an animation?

Tags: javafx, progress-bar

I created a progress bar and changed the bar color.

Is it possible to add an animation to the progress bar like bootstrap animated progress bar?

Here is the example:
[link here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress-animated)

Actually, I find a solution, but It's not a nice one.

**css**

```
.progress-bar-1 > .bar {
-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(
    from 0em 0.75em to 0.75em 0px,
    repeat,
    -fx-accent 0%,
    -fx-accent 49%,
    derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 50%,
    derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 99%
);}

.progress-bar-2 > .bar {
-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(
    from 0.25em 0.75em to 1em 0px,
    repeat,
    -fx-accent 0%,
    -fx-accent 49%,
    derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 50%,
    derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 99%
);}

.progress-bar-3 > .bar {
-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(
    from 0.5em 0.75em to 1.25em 0px,
    repeat,
    -fx-accent 0%,
    -fx-accent 49%,
    derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 50%,
    derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 99%
);}

.progress-bar-4 > .bar {
-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(
    from 0.75em 0.75em to 1.5em 0px,
    repeat,
    -fx-accent 0%,
    -fx-accent 49%,
    derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 50%,
    derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 99%
);}

.progress-bar-5 > .bar {
-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(
    from 1em 0.75em to 1.75em 0px,
    repeat,
    -fx-accent 0%,
    -fx-accent 49%,
    derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 50%,
    derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 99%
);}

.progress-bar-6 > .bar {
-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(
    from 1.25em 0.75em to 2em 0px,
    repeat,
    -fx-accent 0%,
    -fx-accent 49%,
    derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 50%,
    derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 99%
);}

.progress-bar-7 > .bar {
-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(
    from 1.5em 0.75em to 2.25em 0px,
    repeat,
    -fx-accent 0%,
    -fx-accent 49%,
    derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 50%,
    derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 99%
);}

.progress-bar-8 > .bar {
-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(
    from 1.75em 0.75em to 2.5em 0px,
    repeat,
    -fx-accent 0%,
    -fx-accent 49%,
    derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 50%,
    derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 99%
);}

.progress-bar-9 > .bar {
-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(
    from 2em 0.75em to 2.75em 0px,
    repeat,
    -fx-accent 0%,
    -fx-accent 49%,
    derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 50%,
    derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 99%
);}

.progress-bar-10 > .bar {
-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(
    from 2.25em 0.75em to 3em 0px,
    repeat,
    -fx-accent 0%,
    -fx-accent 49%,
    derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 50%,
    derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 99%
);}

.progress-bar-11 > .bar {
-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(
    from 2.5em 0.75em to 3.25em 0px,
    repeat,
    -fx-accent 0%,
    -fx-accent 49%,
    derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 50%,
    derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 99%
);}

.progress-bar-12 > .bar {
-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(
    from 2.75em 0.75em to 3.5em 0px,
    repeat,
    -fx-accent 0%,
    -fx-accent 49%,
    derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 50%,
    derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 99%
);}
```

I create 12 css. And use AnimationTimer to loop this 12 css.

Like:

```
    String str = "progress-bar-%d";
    progress.getStyleClass().add(String.format(str, i));
    AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer(){
        @Override
        public void handle(long l){
            if(j != 10) {j++; return;}
            j = 0;
            progress.getStyleClass().removeAll(String.format(str, i));
            i++;
            if(i == 13){
                i = 1;
            }
            progress.getStyleClass().add(String.format(str, i));
        }
    };
    timer.start();
```

**fxml**

```
<ProgressBar fx:id="progress" prefWidth="200"  progress="0.5"  />
```

Comment: Can you show us your code please

Comment: Follow [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539642/progressbar-animated-javafx/18543205#18543205). There you will find a link to another answer of the author where the CSS properties are changed with animation. Namely, get the .bar selector of progressbar by lookup, then build a string observable value where the "from" part of "linear-gradient" is bound to other numeric observable value, and bind the string observable value to style of bar.

Comment: You said .bar selector of progressbar by lookup, That's what I did, but it give me null, could you help me check? Node bar = progress.lookup(".bar");

Answer (score 1):

I have realized this with the folowing code:

```
// Set the max status
int maxStatus = 12;
// Create the Property that holds the current status count
IntegerProperty statusCountProperty = new SimpleIntegerProperty(1);
// Create the timeline that loops the statusCount till the maxStatus
Timeline timelineBar = new Timeline(
        new KeyFrame(
                // Set this value for the speed of the animation
                Duration.millis(300),
                new KeyValue(statusCountProperty, maxStatus)
        )
);
// The animation should be infinite
timelineBar.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
timelineBar.play();
// Add a listener to the statusproperty
statusCountProperty.addListener((ov, statusOld, statusNewNumber) -> {
    int statusNew = statusNewNumber.intValue();
    // Remove old status pseudo from progress-bar
    bar.pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("status" + statusOld.intValue()), false);
    // Add current status pseudo from progress-bar
    bar.pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("status" + statusNew), true);
});
```

All without making a lookup(what is not recommended), nor changing the CSS(which is by the way really "time/memory consuming" if you make it really often).

You CSS will look something like this:

```
.progress-bar > .bar {
    ...
}
.progress-bar:status1 > .bar {
    ...
}

.progress-bar:status2 > .bar {
    ...
}
...
```

You could also use css-classes instead of the hole pseudo thing, but that is you choice.

Happy Coding,
Kalasch