# Can CSS in Javafx be used for animations?

Tags: java, css, javafx

Here is the link to the animations in CSS https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Can you use these in Javafx?

Comment: JavaFX css is similar to `W3C CSS`, but it is not the same. There are properties from the latter which are supported in JavaFX, and there are properties which aren't. For a complete reference, please have a look at [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html)

Answer (score 7):

*Yes, in embedded HTML with CSS*

JavaFX has a [WebView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) control which handles CSS animations according to  the w3c css animation specification.

*No, in the scene graph (with CSS)*

The JavaFX 8 scene graph does not support animations with the CSS language itself (as in this [w3c css animation specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/)).

*Yes, in the scene graph (with code)*

The following information you probably already know and, so, is likely not the answer you are looking for.

The animation sample you link in your question (bounces, fades, etc.) can be handled in code rather than CSS.  FXExperience provide a [canned animation sample library](http://fxexperience.com/2012/03/canned-animations/) on how to accomplish such things.  Or you can read up on [coding animations in the Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/animation.htm).

You can animate CSS properties from code, see:

- [How to make an animation with CSS in JavaFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676274/how-to-make-the-css-changing-animation-in-javafx-application)